# REGEX para normalizar diferentes situaciones de un texto entre { }

Tags: regex

Estoy trabajando un documento en LaTeX que tiene algunas anomalías y me gustaría normalizar.

Estos son unos ejemplos:

Actualmente:

```
\textit{todos los valles se elevaron. }Lorem ipsum
\textit{todos los valles se elevaron. } Dolor sit amet
\textit{elévense los valles, }encuentran su plena realización en
\textit{consectetur adipiscing elit }sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

Cambiar por:

```
\textit{todos los valles se elevaron}. Lorem ipsum
\textit{todos los valles se elevaron}. Dolor sit amet
\textit{elévense los valles}, encuentran su plena realización en
\textit{consectetur adipiscing elit} sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

En definitiva lo que quiero es sacar varios elementos como el espacio en blanco o la coma, el punto, del `}` de cierre.

No soy experto en REGEX, investigando encontré este, que me encuentra el caso de los espacios en blanco:

```
(\\textit{(?:\{??[^\{]*? \}))
```

Pero:

1. No sé cómo hacer el reemplazo con ese REGEX.
2. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de encontrar todo en un REGEX y reemplazar, sacando fuera de `}` lo que yo le indique, por ejemplo, el punto, la coma, una coma y un espacio, un punto y un espacio...

Comment: 1. Y si uno agarra eso con awk, no será que la logra?

Comment: ¿Qué es awk, @Alfabravo?

Comment: Awk es un paquetillo que comúnmente se incluye en distros Linux y permite procesar rápidamente archivos, reemplazando patrones en el archivo por otra cosa que uno le indique, permitiendo incluso usar variables y tal para reusar el contenido de cada línea y darle formato. Voy a tratar de ver si logro hacer algo así como respuesta

Comment: Te lo agredecería, pues tengo que trabajar una enorme cantidad de texto normalizando varias situaciones y Awk podría ser de gran ayuda.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿como estas procesando actualmente los archivos? ¿en que lenguaje te gustaría hacerlo? ¿que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Considera que no es lo mismo buscar-reemplazar que buscar-cortar-pegar.
Dependería que la implementación de expresiones regulares que uses soporte **aserciones de búsqueda**.

Una alternativa sería con php y **grupos de captura**, dividiendo cada línea en tres partes:

- Del inicio hasta antes de la coincidencia (caracteres a eliminar).
- La coincidencia
- Después de la coincidencia hasta el final de línea

```
$original = '\textit{todos los valles se elevaron. }Lorem ipsum
\textit{todos los valles se elevaron. } Dolor sit amet
\textit{elévense los valles, }encuentran su plena realización en
\textit{consectetur adipiscing elit }sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et';

$nuevo = '';
foreach( explode("\n", $original) as $linea ){

    /*               |----| 1er grupo
                           |------| 2do grupo
                                    |---| 3er grupo            */                    
    if( preg_match('/(^.*?)([ ,.]+)}(.*$)/', $linea, $grupos) )
        
        $nuevo .= $grupos[1]       // Desde inicio de linea hasta coincidencia
                . '}'.$grupos[2]   // Antepone el cierre de llave a la coincidencia
                . $grupos[3]       // El resto de la linea después de la llave
                ;
    else 
        $nuevo .= $linea; // Si no hubo coincidencia dejar la linea original
    $nuevo .= "\n"; // Reponemos el salto de linea que dejamos con explode
}
echo $nuevo.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos construyendo paso a paso. Empecemos con el caso más sencillo: un patrón que coincide con `\textit{` `}` con cualquier caracter adentro que no sean llaves.

```
\\textit\{[^{}]*\}
```

- En `[^{}]` los corchetes son una *clase de caracteres*, pero el `^` al inicio lo niega. Es decir, un caracter que no sea `{` ni sea `}`... Pero lo repetimos 0 o más veces con el `*` al final. O sea, cualquier cantidad de caracteres, entre 0 e infinitos.
- Todo el resto es literal.

Segundo paso, antes del cierre de llaves queremos que haya uno o más espacios o puntos o comas:

```
\\textit\{[^{}]*[ ,.]+\}
```

- `[ ,.]+` es uno de esos 3 caracteres, y el `+` lo repite 1 o más veces.

Pero si hubiese más de 1 espacio/coma/punto al final, en realidad todos menos el último coincidirían con `[^{}]*`. Entonces en vez de que trate de coincidir con lo más que pueda, le cambiamos el comportamiento (codicioso) al `*`, usando `*?` para que coincida con lo menos posible.

```
\\textit\{[^{}]*?[ ,.]+\}
```

Eso es todo. Sólo nos resta poner algunos paréntesis para que capture en grupos diferentes, así usamos el texto capturado en el reemplazo. El texto capturado por el primer grupo de paréntesis estará disponible cómo `$1` para el reemplazo, `$2` para el segundo grupo capturado, y así sucesivamente.

En definitiva, deberías usar el patrón:

```
(\\textit\{[^{}]*?)([ ,.]+)(\})
```

Y reemplazar por:

```
$1$3$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias alternativas.

Quizás la más sencilla sea usar esta regex (Necesitarás un motor de bbdd compatible con PCRE)

```
([^}\p{L}\\]++)[}]
```

Sustituir por:

```
}$1
```

Tienes una demo aquí: https://regex101.com/r/2zzg4V/1

Básicamente lo que hacemos es buscar caracteres antes del fin de llave siempre que no sean letras, ni contrabarras ni el propio fin de llave.

Este sistema tiene la ventaja de que es sencillo y que debería funcionar con cualquier tipo de alfabeto.

La desventaja (o quizás no lo es) es que no discrimina por `\textit`, lo hará para cualquier cierre de llave.

También se aplicará a llaves que no formen parte de ninguna etiqueta como textit. Por ejemplo `foo {bar } baz`. Aunque desconozco si este último caso es válido en latex.

Si deseas especificar las etiquetas donde se aplica o no te interesa cambiar las llaves de ese último caso, podrías usar esta regex:

```
(\\\w++[{](?:\\[&%$#_{}~^\\]|\p{L}++|(?:[^\\](?!(?:[^\p{L}\\}])*+[}]))++)*+)([^}\\]++)[}]
```

Desenrollada:

```
(
    \\\w++ [{]
    (?:  \\[&%$#_{}~^\\]
    |    \p{L}++
    |    (?:
         [^\\] (?! (?:[^\p{L}\\}])*+ [}] )
         )++
    )*+
) ([^}\\]++) [}]
```

Remplazar por:

```
$1}$2
```

Tienes una demo aquí: https://regex101.com/r/vRXGPk/1

La expresión regular es relativamente compleja porque **está pensada para soportar caracteres escapados dentro de las etiquetas**. Por ejemplo:

```
\textit{hola \{llaves\} adios. }Otra frase
```

Si necesitas discriminar por etiqueta simplemente cambia `\w++` por lo que necesites.